# Search not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, fullcalendar

I have no idea why this does not work? The select option works without any problems, but the search field does not work...

Nothing happens. The console displays the input from the search field correctly. No error, nothing.

```
<select id='selector'>
    <option value="all">Alle</option>
    (more data)
</select>

<input class="form-control search" name="search" id="search" type="text" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#selector').change(onSelectChangeFeed); // select option
   function onSelectChangeFeed() { 
      var feed = $(this).find(':selected').data('feed');
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', feed);
       console.log(feed);
   };

   $('#search').change(onSearchChangeFeed); // search field
   function onSearchChangeFeed() { 
      var stext = $(this).val();
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', stext);
         console.log(stext);
   };
});
</script>
```

please help me :)

**EDIT**

i think the problem is here:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
   var selector = ['all', event.color].indexOf($('#selector').val()) >= '' || ['all', event.category].indexOf($('#selector').val()) >= '' || ['all', event.title].indexOf($('#selector').val()) >= '';
   var searchfield = event.color.indexOf($('#search').val()) >= '' || event.category.indexOf($('#search').val()) >= '' || event.title.indexOf($('#search').val()) >= '';
   return (selector, searchfield);
}
```

Comment: What is it doing at the moment? Does it show an error? did the search just not happen? "Doesn't work" is a very unclear statement if we don't know what it does instead.

Comment: I guess this might be the problem : `$(this).val()` Are you sure $(this) work as you expect? Try `$('#search').val()`

Comment: It's not clear what is going wrong. Please clarify. The code will run when the textbox value changes (you must unfocus the box, of course) and will print the typed value correctly. Depending what you type, it might remove an event source from the calendar (although what this functionality has to do with "searching" is anyone's guess, but that's a separate issue). So you'll have to give us a bit more detail about what your actual problem is.

Comment: Nothing happens. The console displays the input from the search field correctly. No error, nothing.
$('#search').val() makes no difference!

Comment: topic edited...

Comment: Do not mark questions as solved, or include the solution within the question. If you solved it, write an Answer in the answers section. Then you may get upvotes for it. You can also "accept" your own answer. That's the whole point of the structure of this website as a question/answer system. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson ah ok. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself. I changed

```
return (selector, searchfield);
```

to

```
return (selector && searchfield);
```

and now it works as intended.

Answer (score -1):

Your `this` is not what you expect to be, so try to get the val using the input element id. `$('#search').val()`

Comment: a very simple test, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/473/ shows that `this` represents the textbox perfectly happily. This is normal JS behaviour.